# Azure Logic apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am creating a LogicApp with a simple request trigger as given in the example given below.I am trying to pass parameter using 'Start-AZLogicApp' cmdlet. While the Logic App does get instantiated when I run the cmdlet, the parameter does not pass and the workflow fails.

Start-AzLogicApp:-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.logicapp/start-azlogicapp?view=azps-1.1.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-1.0.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint

JSON:-

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "address": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "address"
  ]
}
```

Payload:-

```
//
{
   "address": "21 2nd Street, New York, New York"
}
//
```

This works fine if I post the callback url in a browser and pass the parameters ,however if I use the above mentioned powershell cmdlet to trigger the logic app, then no parameter is passed. The actual cmdlet I am trying is:

```
$paramer='"address": "21 2nd Street, New York, New York"'
$paramerStart-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName "resource1" -Name "calling -logicap" -Parameters $paramer -TriggerName "manual"
```

Need some help to find out what should I pass that the HTTP request trigger accepts the passed parameter by this cmdlet.

Answer (score 2):

The `Start-AzLogicApp` method is used to start a logic app, the result is equivalent to using `Run Trigger`, it won't pass request body. And the parameter, it's the dynamic parameters, about parameters in the logic app you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language#parameters).

If you want to pass your request body, you could use Postman to do it.You could send it in the raw.
[image]

And don't forget to `Content-Type` in the header.
[image]

Then the result will be right.

[image]